Getting an Error during Codepipeline deploy using elastic-beanstalk
I am trying to deploy a simple Flask app using elastic beanstalk and codepipeline. I have successfully launched my elastic beanstalk environment. However when I try to deploy my github code through the code pipeline it fails to deploy.
at the beginning, this is what my python.config file in .ebextensions folder looked like:
option_settings:
  "aws:elasticbeanstalk:container:python":
    WSGIPath: application:application

However, the deploy failed due to the following error:

Error: fail to install dependencies with requirements.txt file with error Command /var/app/venv/staging-LQM1lest/bin/pip install -r requirements.txt failed with error exit status 1. Stderr:ERROR: Could not install packages due to an OSError: [Errno 28] No space left on device.

running df -h in the EC2 instance i got:
Filesystem        Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
devtmpfs          4.0M     0  4.0M   0% /dev
tmpfs             453M     0  453M   0% /dev/shm
tmpfs             181M  5.9M  176M   4% /run
/dev/nvme0n1p1     10G  2.8G  7.3G  28% /

tmpfs             453M  354M   99M  79% /tmp
/dev/nvme0n1p128   10M  1.3M  8.7M  13% /boot/efi
tmpfs              91M     0   91M   0% /run/user/1000

I thought it might got to do with the /tmp folder, I changed my python.config to this:
commands:
  command1: 
    command: mount -o remount,size=1G /tmp
    env:
      TMPDIR : /var/tmp
  command2: 
    command: export TMPDIR=/var/tmp

container_commands:
  01_cleanup_tmp:
    command: rm -rf /tmp/*
  00bootup:
    command: echo export TMPDIR=/var/tmp >> /etc/profile.d/custom_tmpdir.sh
  01bootup:
    command: mount -o remount,size=1G /tmp
  02bootup:
    command: export TMPDIR=/var/tmp

YES there is redundancy here..., but i wanted to make sure that installing the python packages won't fail.
when i tried to retry the deploy stage or even rebuild the environment the deploy failed, this time the error message was:

Deployment completed, but with errors: During an aborted deployment, some instances may have deployed the new application version. To ensure all instances are running the same version, re-deploy the appropriate application version. Failed to deploy application. Unsuccessful command execution on instance id(s) 'i-069d8747d188df12e'. Aborting the operation. [Instance: i-069d8747d188df12e] Command failed on instance. An unexpected error has occurred [ErrorCode: 0000000001].

There is nothing helpful it the eb-engine.log...
What to do here?
I tried to create the entire EB application for scratch, nothing works....
Another question: when i connect to the EB ec2 instance, i don't see any of the commands' results that i defined in the python.config. For example, i don't see the environment variable TMPDIR or that /tmp was resized to 1G. why is that? how do i know that these commands were actually executed. (i don't see any reference to them in the cfn-init.cmd.log file)
Thank you,
